# Why don't my column headings line up?

Tags: html, css

I set the same width for my column headers as my data rows.  But they refuse to line up.

I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bwdc78tr/

Here's my CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #013499;
    margin: 0;
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: #7690C5;
    bottom: 60px;
    float: left;
    height: calc(100% - 120px);
    top: 60px;
    width: 200px;
}

#content {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    bottom: 60px;
    float: left;
    height: calc(100% - 120px);
    top: 60px;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    margin: -60px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #013499;
}

.buttons {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#dropDownButton {
    vertical-align: -5px;
}

#WholeNumber {
    width: 135px;
}

#LookupSection {
    color: white;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 220px;
}

.WholeNumberCell {
    background-color: white;
    color: #000000;
}

#ImageDataTable {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-spacing: 0;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.ImageDataCell {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: #000000;
}

#WholeNumberDiv {
    margin-left: 100px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.send_button {
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

The table is dynamically created.  I have read several sites of how to create tables but they all explain basic things.  The techniques always break down when expanded upon.  I can't find anything that explains more advanced things so if anyone knows any good links then please post them.

I think one problem may be that the example I am using is a staticly sized table (http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html) and mine is dynamic.  Any ideas on how to adapt this?

Comment: I have seen several things which I cannot understand. you use some class for your table but you type your css inline into the html??? you would better create a td class and stick everything in the css. Secondly why do you put different width between your th and relevant td? this will only mess a bit more your code up. I would strongly suggest to create a very simple table, then you confirm this is fine an only then you apply a css in a separate file and not in the html file itself

Comment: Simply put, I am trying different things to figure out how to make this work.  And if you look carefully, you will notice that the different widths are for different columns.  The widths for the headers match the data but one of them is being ignored.  And this example is a simplified version of the application.  The table behaves differently when taken out of context therefore it makes simplifying it too much pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your table `ImageDataTable` you have your `thead` then in the first `tr` you are setting the properties to `display:block` when it should be `display: table-row` Further down in your code you set `tbody id="TmageDataBody"` to `display: block` when it should be `display: table-row-group;`

See [your updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bwdc78tr/1/)

Comment: I changed from block to table-row and now I can not get my table to scroll, it just expands to fill the entire page.  Any idea on how to correct this or should I create a new thread?

Comment: Not sure I understand. In the fiddle your table still scrolls. With the code changes I suggested your columns are lined up and is causing your table to be vertically taller because all the content is swished into place.

Comment: Whats a "swish" as you are using it?  Never heard that before.  Also my table does NOT scroll in the example.  If you look carefully you will see the whole page scrolls.  The goal is for a scrolling table.

Comment: Hahaha I meant "squished"... sorry typo. If you want just the table to be scrollable then you can add overflow:scroll; to your #content ID. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/bwdc78tr/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

1. Your first `<th>` is closed with a `</div>` instead of the obvious. Whenver I see HTML giving very unusual and unexpected behavior, I tend to look for these issues using the W3 Validator; most of its output is irrelevant to me, but it's at least good at finding non-matching tags. Browsers often render these things in case they're minor HTML mistakes, but sometimes bad end tags can badly break the format.
2. You define width in the `<th>` block, but then you override it with the ancient `width` HTML attribute. If you want the headers to dictate the width, only set the width there.
3. This could be just jsfiddle, but the space the table was given didn't allow it to give cells their full intended width. I got it to look okay by setting `width: 300%;` so that it had horizontal scrollbars. You also had a typo on the `"widht"` property.

EDIT: As you indicated, seems there was more to it. You also had the `display: block;` property set on some of the elements via CSS. This overrides the element's default, which is `display: table-cell;` and `display: table-row;`, which is what gives it its signature constant-width behavior.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the div / th error.  I fixed it but it did not help.  The reason I have the width on the data rows is the table looks even worse without them, you can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/bwdc78tr/2/ .

Answer (score 0):

Generally you are trying to exert too much control over your table.

First, remove the inline styles from the `thead > tr` and `tbody` elements that are setting `display:block`.  You generally don't want this when you're using tables.  Just doing this will get your columns to align.

Now remove all of the inline styles setting the column widths... an easier way to to this is to use a `colgroup`:

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 50%"></col>
    <col style="width: 20%"></col>
    <col style="width: 30%"></col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Header 1</th>
     <th>Header 2</th>
     <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Header 1</td>
     <td>Header 2</td>
     <td>Header 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now this leaves the problem that I BELIEVE you were trying to deal with from the get-go, and that is that your table data creates a table wider than your available space.  You can handle this in a few ways. A couple of suggestions:

• Put the table in a container set to scroll its overflow:

```
 div.tableContainer {
   overflow-x: auto;
 }
```

• Set up the table to truncate the cell content:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td, th {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Generally, your goal should be to have a table with as little inline CSS as possible.

Comment: The reason I have it that way is I need stationary column headers with scrollable data.  I was trying to mimic this http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html